# detecting clicked tableView

Tags: swift, macos

Regardless of selection, I need to know the tableview involved with a mouse click. Consider

```
func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.selectedTableView = (notification.object as! NSTableView)
    switch selectedTableView {
    case oneTableView?:
        print("one")
        break
    case twoTableView?:
        print("two")
        break
    default:
        print("wtf \(selectedTableView)")
    }
}
```

table/view 'two' is a detail of 'one'. Selecting a row in 'one' alters the content for tableview 'two' (header -> detail). But if the user clicked a row already selected, no notification as the selection did not change.  Basi I just need to know the last tableview / column clicked.

Is mouseDown approach better (way more difficult) but I do **not** see objective-c or 'UI' equivalent delegate methods in the AppKit -> NSTableView -> NSTableView for column or row selection methods?

Comment: why dont you use `UITableViewDelegate` and save yourself all of this trouble

Comment: `UITableViewDelegate` is UIKit, not Cocoa.

Comment: Try using `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool` instead, return true in the end of the function and do your operations before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, on osx in the current AppKit (8.2.1) state on Sierra this is not doable.

My gui is using a single action control for a set of header/detail tableViews and I needed to know which was in effect, so I'm to mandating an empty selection in the detail table view to indicate the header view selection is to be used.

But I would like to know why osx swift doesn't have a comparable delegate method set that ios or objective-c have?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is, within this UITableViewDelegate Function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let tableOne = tableView as? TableOne {// do code here to other table}
    else if let tableTwo = tableView as? TableTwo {//do code here to other table}
}
```

Comment: Uh, this is osx. Is there an osx equivalent routine? I have this function, specifying NSTableView but it doesn't get called?